# How do I remove Ubuntu GNOME's "mouse position functions"?

Tags: gnome, screen, top

What I mean by "mouse position function" is, for instance, when you put the mouse cursor on the top left edge of the screen to show up the Applications and on the bottom to show the message tray.

I already tried to search for it but I could not find anything.

Comment: Those features are commonly called "hot corners", which may help you with your search!

Comment: Thank you dazzle! Thanks to your help I could find a good solution, which was to install two extensions from http://www.extensions.gnome.com/ to remove the top-left corner and message tray! :)

Comment: Which version of Gnome shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are varying extensions on https://extensions.gnome.org/ you can use, including:

- [Insensitive Message Tray](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/616/insensitive-message-tray/) - which

  > *"Renders the bottom message tray insensitive so that it doesn't show
  >   up automatically when the mouse pointer is placed at the bottom edge
  >   of the screen. However you can still access the message tray using
  >   Super+M."*

  This functionality is also now included the [Dask to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension.
- [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) - which:

  > *"This extension disables the top left hot corners. You can still
  >   click on Activities or press the dedicated key to reach the overview.
  >   Since 3.8, should work with other extensions modifying the Activities
  >   button. On versions prior to 3.8, may not disable other hotcorners in
  >   multiscreen configurations and won't work on fallback/flashback
  >   mode."*

You may have to use other extensions depending on which version of Gnome shell you are using.